# Is there any fastest way to run shell commands in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, shell

I want to run a number of shell commands let say 50 or 60 commands one by one.
For example:

```
const arr = ['/hello', '/temp', '/temp2', '/temp3', '/temp5', .......]
arr.forEach(dir => {
    // Run shell command like ls and pass dir as argument
})
```

I tried multiple way's like using exec command but it takes too much time. I also tried spawn command but it gives me ENONET error.
Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I want to know the fastest way to run this

Comment: May you share an [mcve] of the spawning? So we can see the error?

Comment: If things are slow it's because the commands themselves are taking a lot of time; it almost certainly has nothing to do with Node.

Comment: `ls` on a dir can take time, especially if you `-R` for the recursive list. Pointy is correct, it's not Node processing the command, it's your OS in this case.

Comment: running command in forEach as spawn('ls') gives me error: spawn ls ENOENT

Comment: That means the directory or file name cannot be found. Without more information, nobody can help you.

Comment: @SterlingArcher then how can I improve this ? I mean I wanna run it faster

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm primarily a node developer. But I did a quick search and maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1345268/ls-command-very-slow) will help you

Comment: Are you aware that invoking an external command like `ls` is the slowest way to list files in Node? Is this still the approach you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

The commands can be passed to one shell instead of invoking a separate shell for each command; that shell will still invoke the commands *one by one.*

```
exec("ls "+arr.join(";ls "), …)
```